# Proguard obfuscates Activity names in a merged library manifest

Tags: android, proguard

I have several application projects which use a common library project. I recently tried moving some common Activity declarations from each application project's AndroidManifest.xml into the library's manifest, and enabled manifest merging with `manifestmerger.enabled=true` in `project.properties`.

Everything works fine in a debug build, but release builds (obfuscated by Proguard) fail with an `ActivityNotFoundException`. This is because Proguard is obfuscating the names of Activities which are declared in the library manifest, but not those in the application manifest.

I have examined the merged `bin/AndroidManifest.xml` file for the application project, and it correctly has the Activity names listed.

Can someone please suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

The standard Ant build process invokes the aapt tool to create a ProGuard configuration (bin/proguard.txt) that preserves the necessary classes (e.g. all activities that it deems used). If that doesn't work for your project structure (maybe a bug or an unsupported case), you can preserve the classes yourself in your proguard-project.txt:

```
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
```

If the resulting application is still missing other classes, you can find more manual configuration in the ProGuard manual > Examples > [A complete Android application](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication).

Comment: @ Eric, I think it's a bug in the build system (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36077). Do you have any workaround or suggestion?

Comment: @user802421 Explicitly adding the above -keep lines should work around it.

Comment: @ Eric, adding explicitly still didn't work. Only class definition in the manifest of the apk project was kept. Right now I need to turn merger off and copy everything from lib project. :(